# When Running Unit Tests "No tests were found" using ReSharper and Jasmine on Visual Studio Cordova

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

When running unit tests using ReSharper and Jasmine as the unit testing framework I get "no tests were found in file" in my visual studio cordova project. But when I run my visual studio library project it works fine with the unit tests. It seems like in the cordova project ReSharper cannot detect the tests. Has anyone else ran into this issue? What was your resolution?

Comment: I have run into issues with running JavaScript test through ReSharper in the past.  I have since moved on to using the karma test runner as it also integrates nicely with a build server.  The Visual Studio Chutzpah plugin also works pretty nicely and integrates with the build server as well.  I use ReSharper extensively, but have found other options for JavaScript testing to be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew, I was able to get the jasmine tests running in ReSharper. I had to create a separate test project in Visual Studio. ReSharper was able to then recognize the jasmine code. I also had to add `///<reference src="javascript source" >` for each source file that was required in my spec files.